# Start BottomSheetFragment for result

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, bottom-sheet

I want to get results from BottomSheetFragment. I tried to do it through `getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, null);` inside

```
    @Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, null);
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
}
```

but activity's method onActivityResult not called. What am I doing wrong?

```
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Toast.makeText(this, requestCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Dialog start method

```
BottomSheetDialogFragment bottomSheetFragment = new BottomSheetDialogFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bottomSheetFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            bottomSheetFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), bottomSheetFragment.getTag());
```

Comment: Try to call `getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, null);` after `super.onDismiss(dialog);`

Comment: And show `Toast` after `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);`

Comment: @DineshShingadiya didn't help (

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onActivityResult()` is used for getting a result from another Activity.

More on this: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result

If you want to send some data from Fragment to Activity, you can do it either by defining an interface or call a method in the Activity by casting it to the specific Activity.

```
class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  YourBottomSheetDialogFragment bottomSheetFragment = new YourBottomSheetDialogFragment();
  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
  bottomSheetFragment.setArguments(bundle);
  bottomSheetFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), bottomSheetFragment.getTag());
 }

 public void setResultFromFragment(String data) {
  ...
 }
}

/**
* Calling Activity's method from Fragment
*/
class YourBottomSheetDialogFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

 @Override
 public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setResultFromFragment("");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I decided to implement the interface as suggested to me by *DEVV911*

```
interface OnFinishedListener {

        void onFinished(ArrayList<TestCard> acceptList, ArrayList<TestCard> rejectList);

        void onFailure(Throwable t);
    }
```

add it into dialog's construction method

```
private TestActivityContract.OnFinishedListener onFinishedListener;

BottomSheetFragment(TestActivityContract.OnFinishedListener onFinishedListener) {
    this.onFinishedListener = onFinishedListener;
}
```

And call the onFinished method in onDismiss

```
    @Override
public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onDismiss(dialog);
    onFinishedListener.onFinished(acceptList, rejectList);
}
```